# Getting `undefined is not an object` when I'm Reading json Data

Tags: react-native

Why I'm Getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.artist.name')` when I'm Reading data via React Native?

`this.props.artist.name` haven't access to `name`, What Should I do?
I want to use This Module for playing audio file and I want to read from my data, same as (https://github.com/devnacho/react-native-music-player/blob/master/app/components/artists/ArtistShow.js)
I Have 3 Page, 1:Router page 2:ArtistShow 3:player

**This is My Data:**

```
    const artist = [
      {
        name: "Soda Stereo",
        background: "http://cnnchile.com/uploads/imagenes/14344020424867_breaking.jpg",
        songs: [
          {
            title: "Un Misil En Mi Placard",
            album: "Comfort y Musica Para Volar",
            url: "https://www.freesound.org/data/previews/208/208096_3767678-lq.mp3",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**And This is My ArtistShow Code:**

```
class ArtistShow extends Component {


  renderStickyHeader() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.stickySection}>
        <Text style={styles.stickySectionTitle}>{this.props.artist.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { onScroll = () => { } } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <ParallaxScrollView
          style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, width: window.width, height: window.height }}
          parallaxHeaderHeight={PARALLAX_HEADER_HEIGHT}
          stickyHeaderHeight={STICKY_HEADER_HEIGHT}
          onScroll={onScroll}
          renderStickyHeader={this.renderStickyHeader.bind(this)}
        >

        </ParallaxScrollView>
        <View style={styles.headerClose}>
          <Icon onPress={Actions.pop} name="chevron-left" size={15} color="#fff" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ArtistShow;
```

**This is Router Page:**

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
                <Scene key="root">
                    <Scene key="artistahow" component={ArtistShow} title="ArtistShow" initial />
                    <Scene key="player" component={Player} title="Player" />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Umm, where are you binding the data to the component? I don't see where you initialized the properties. Can you place your entire code for the component?

Comment: I updated my Code

Comment: Did you create the artist const in the same file as the ArtistShow class?

Comment: I Created This:  ```const artist = [
  {
    name: "Soda Stereo",
    background: "http://cnnchile.com/uploads/imagenes/14344020424867_breaking.jpg",
    songs: [
      {
        title: "Un Misil En Mi Placard",
        album: "Comfort y Musica Para Volar",
        url: "https://www.freesound.org/data/previews/208/208096_3767678-lq.mp3",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), props are passed either dynamically `Actions.scenekey(obj)` or statically, in your navigation tree:

`<Scene key='scenekey' component={MyComponent} artist={yourArtistObj} />`

Since your Scene is **initial**, you should use the second method. However, this is not recommended and not useful. If you're going to define it like this, you should better initialize the `artist` variable in your Component. *You don't have to pass it as a prop.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're passing artist as a property to this component and artist is an array, so you would have to do something like `this.props.artist[0].name` which will give you the first artist's name.

Comment: Dear @matt-aft I got this: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.artist[0]')`

Comment: Then it's because you're not passing your data to that component. Where/how are you using the artistshow component and how are you passing the artists to it?

Comment: Dear @matt-aft I'm new in react native and I want to play a mp3 file with `react-native-music-player` I Just Copied This page code for playing my music But not work, (https://github.com/devnacho/react-native-music-player/blob/master/app/components/artists/ArtistShow.js), My flux router works fine, But I Can't play music from my json data, Can you help me to solve my problem and do you have a simple demo code for playing music, Thanks

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I can help, feel free to start a chat

Comment: Thank you @Enie , I'm Ready And I can Give you Team Access too

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/149402/helping-react-native-undefined?tab=general